# Sorting a dictionary via multiple parameters

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary `IDictionary answersDictionary<Country, List<Answer>>`, where `Country` contains information on country and `List<Answer>` is a list of  `Answer` objects, which have a property `State` that can be `final`, `draft`, `comment`.

I need to sort the dictionary in a way, that its sorted by:

1. Number of `draft` answers for country
2. Number of `comment` answers for country
3. By `Country.Name`

And, at the end get only the keys of the dictionary.

I have done the following:

```
    IDictionary<Country, List<Answer>> answersDictionary = Database.Answer
        .GroupBy(a => a.Country).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.ToList());

    answersDictionary.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value.Where(a => a.State == AnswerState.Draft).Count())
        .ThenByDescending(d => d.Value.Where(a => a.State == AnswerState.Comment).Count())
        .ThenBy(d => d.Key.Name);
```

And at the end `List<Country> finalResult=answersDictionary.Keys;`

But, the results are not correct, as they are returned sorted only by `Draft` and in `ascending` order. Any suggestions, what's the issue?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you need to sort something, a dictionary is the wrong collection to choose. Dictionaries are key based, not index based - you might want to consider just creating a class that will hold a `Country` and a `List<Answer>` and store that into a `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign your second query to a variable. Try this:

```
IDictionary<Country, List<Answer>> answersDictionary = Database.Answer
        .GroupBy(a => a.Country).ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.ToList());

var answerDict = answersDictionary.OrderByDescending(d => d.Value.Count(a => a.State == AnswerState.Draft))
                                  .ThenByDescending(d => d.Value.Count(a => a.State == AnswerState.Comment))
                                  .ThenBy(d => d.Key.Name)
                                  .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value);

List<Country> finalResult = answerDict.Keys.ToList();
```

Comment: But in that case, the variable doesn't have Keys.